# intellij project structure need to reimport module SDK and build it after swtiching branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is there a way that we can avoid reimporting module SDK and build it after switching Git branch?
It is trivial that we have to reimport JDK as follows steps:
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Module SDK.

Thanks in advance.

[image: here]

Comment: Does it help if you disable Maven auto importing? (Settings / Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Reload project after changes in the build scripts)

Comment: @EgorKlepikov It is strange that today when I switched to other branches it does not need to reimport the module SDKs. I mean I didn't change any configuration and just enable Maven auto importing.